# How to stop access user to audio files in app with flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

In my app there are collections of audio files that I want user listen to them after buying and downloading them, but can't copy the files. in the other hand I want to restrict user to just listen to them by the app not with other app or copy them for their-own. 
the only solution that I have got is to encrypt the files and decrypt them before playing in app.
is there any standard way for this issue? if it's the right solution how should I implement it?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, did you found solution for this issue? I have the same problem too

Comment: I've just answered my question @coolbeatz71

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem with this way that at first I extracted audio file as byte then save the data as string in new file with an extension that I specified. So when user clicks on the play button the response function reverse this procedure so that the `mp3` file can be created and be used. and also when user clicks on stop button after stopping the file, the file will be removed so that no one can have it.
last but not least you must save the files just in app directory because no one can access them unless with root access which is another obstacle.
this is my implementation:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class MediaFile {
  Future<String> get docPath async {
    Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return appDocDir.path;
  }

  Future<Uint8List> get audioFileData async {
    final String path = await docPath;
    final String theFilePath = '$path/test.mp3';
    final File theFile = new File(theFilePath);
    if (await theFile.exists()) {
      return await theFile.readAsBytes();
    } else {
      File file = await FilePicker.getFile();
      return await file.readAsBytes();
    }
  }

  Future<String> dataToString() async {
    Uint8List data = await audioFileData;
    return new String.fromCharCodes(data);
  }

  Future<File> saveMediaAsString(String fileName, String fileContent) async {
    String path = await docPath;
    Directory dataDir = new Directory('$path/data');
    if (await dataDir.exists()) {
      File file = new File('$path/data/$fileName');
      return file.writeAsString(fileContent);
    }
    await dataDir.create();
    File file = new File('$path/data/$fileName');
    return file.writeAsString(fileContent);
  }

  Future<String> readFromStringMediaFile(String fileName) async {
    String path = await docPath;
    File file = new File('$path/data/$fileName');
    return file.readAsString();
  }

  Uint8List stringToData(dataStr) {
    List<int> list = dataStr.codeUnits;
    return new Uint8List.fromList(list);
  }

  Future<File> createAudioFile(String fileName, Uint8List bytes) async {
    String path = await docPath;
    File file = new File('$path/$fileName');
    return await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
  }

  //here you can see how to use them
  Future<File> testFile() async {
    String dataStr = await dataToString();
    File savedFile = await saveMediaAsString('codedFile', dataStr);
    String contentSavedFile = await readFromStringMediaFile('codedFile');
    Uint8List bytes = stringToData(contentSavedFile);
    return await createAudioFile('test.mp3', bytes);
  }
}
```

downward of this way is that user experience a bit latency when playing audio file which can be tolerated with showing a loading after user click the play button.

Comment: With your solution, the user can still copy the mp3 while playing it. A better solution is to decrypt the file on the fly. Means, deal with streams, and decrypt as the song is being played. I am trying to implement, so your solution will be a good step for me. Thx

Comment: No they can not because after each step the file will be removed and also if they want to access the file they need to login as root which is so hard for them. but for encryption I tried this solution at first it's not practical because for just 9MB file it took me 2 hours encrypting with I5 CPU let alone a mobile device which is so weaker than this

Comment: What if you just encrypt the first 16 bits of the audio. Instead of encrypt the entire file

Comment: This is a good idea, I haven't tried it if you do tell me what happens. Thanks in advance